# MATLAB system command different than pyversion

Tags: python, matlab, miniconda

I am using MATLAB R2019b and have miniconda3 installed and activated on a Linux machine.
I have activated conda on the command line `conda activate` and then started MATLAB (no GUI). I see that there is difference in what the `system` function provides and what the `pyversion` shows:

```
>> system('which python')
/usr/bin/python

ans =

     0

>> pyversion

       version: '3.8'
    executable: '/home/XYZ/miniconda3/bin/python'
       library: '/home/XYZ/miniconda3/lib/libpython3.8.so'
          home: '/home/XYZ/miniconda3'
      isloaded: 0
```

I checked `genenv('PATH')` and .../miniconda3/bin and .../miniconda3/condabin are in the PATH as first two entries as expected.

Executing `which python` on the command line gives the miniconda3 binary.

Similar observation for some other binaries in the miniconda3 path.

**Q: how do I get MATLAB's `system` to recognize the miniconda3 binaries?**

--- EDIT ---

setting `export MATLAB_SHELL=/bin/bash` before starting matlab shows correct binaries with the `system` function.
Then the question becomes why do `getenv` and `system` are disagree before setting the MATLAB_SHELL variable?

Comment: “MATLAB 97”? MATLAB has an internal version number, but they’re not that high up yet. The “R2019b” part is what is normally used to convey version number.

Comment: You need to make sure that the miniconda binary directory comes before the /usr/bin directory on the PATH. MATLAB doesn’t always preserve the shell’s PATH.

Comment: thanks @CrisLuengo. As I mentioned in the post the miniconda3 paths appear as first two entries in the PATH.

Comment: Yes, but now do `system('echo $PATH')`. -- The `system` command starts a new shell, which might or might not inherit environment variables from the MATLAB process. So in this case, the solution would be to do `system('PATH=/home/XYZ/miniconda3/bin/:$PATH which python')`

Comment: What is confusing (as stated in the EDIT) is that I would expect `genenv('PATH')` to provide me the PATH that will be used in whatever shell the `system` call would use. Your comment does the job but I find the behavior of these functions inconsistent.

Comment: `getenv` gets environment variables from MATLAB’s process. Spawned processes do not need to inherit the parent’s environment.

Comment: 2019b release is 9.7 version. Not 97 version